# How can I calculate the logarithm of a matrix using Fortran 77?

Tags: matrix, fortran, linear-algebra, logarithm, intel-mkl

I have to compute the logarithm of a 3x3 matrix (A) in a Fortran 77 program.

In Python I used

`scipy.linalg.logm(A)`

for this job but I don´t find a solution for this task in Fortran.

So far I figured out that this operation is not possible with the built-in functions of Fortran 77. Also I searched in the documentation of the Intel Math Kernel Library, but haven´t found a suitable subroutine. I found the subroutine F01EJ in the NAG Fortran Library, but unfortunatly I have no access to this commercial library. I know the papers of Higham et al., but I would like to avoid to implement the algorithms by myself since I think that this must be a solved problem.

Can anyone provide me with a hint to a subroutine that calculates the matrix logarithm?

**Solution:**

I have implemented a subroutine for the logarithm of a 3x3 matrix according to the way proposed by @kvantour and it worked out fine for me. Maybe the (not very pretty) quick and dirty code of the subroutine is useful for others with the same problem:

```
  subroutine calclogM(M,logM)

  implicit none

  double precision,dimension(3,3)::M,logM,VL,VR,logMapo,VRinv
  integer::n,INFO,LWORK,I,J

  double precision,dimension(3)::WR,WI,logWR,ipiv
  double precision,dimension(24)::WORK

  n=3
  LWORK=24


  call DGEEV( 'N', 'V', n, M, n, WR, WI, VL, n, VR,
 1                  n, WORK, LWORK, INFO )

C Check if all eigenvalues are greater than zero

  if (WR(1) .le. 0.D0) then
    write(*,*) 'Unable to compute matrix logarithm!'
    GOTO 111
  end if

  if (WR(2) .le. 0.D0) then
    write(*,*) 'Unable to compute matrix logarithm!'
    GOTO 111
  end if

  if (WR(3) .le. 0.D0) then
    write(*,*) 'Unable to compute matrix logarithm!'
    GOTO 111
  end if

  DO I = 1, 3
    DO J = 1, 3
        logMapo(I,J) = 0.D0
    END DO
  END DO

C Then Mapo will be a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements 
C are eigenvalues of M. Replace each diagonal element of Mapo by its 
C (natural) logarithm in order to obtain logMapo.

  DO I = 1, 3
    LogMapo(I,I)=log(WR(I))
  END DO


C Calculate inverse of V with LU Factorisation
C Copy VR to VRinv
  DO I = 1, 3
    DO J = 1, 3
        VRinv(I,J) = VR(I,J)
    END DO
  END DO

  call dgetrf( n, n, VRinv, n, ipiv, info )
  write(*,*) 'INFO',INFO

  call dgetri( n, VRinv, n, ipiv, WORK, LWORK, INFO )
  write(*,*) 'INFO',INFO

C Build the logM Matrix
  logM = matmul(matmul(VR,logMapo),VRinv)      

111  end subroutine calclogM
```

Comment: Welcome, please remember to take the Welcome [tour] and read [ask]. Unfortunately, there is no such intrinsic function in Fortran and recommending an external library is off-topic here. I guess if you search for the [methods referenced in the SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.logm.html) you might find Fortran implementations, but searching them for you is off-topic here. But maybe they are too recent to have a Fortran implementation. You might find a C or C++ one and call it from Fortran.

Comment: The C++ Eigen library has matrix logarithm, you may want to try to call it from Fortran. That requires you to write some interfacing C++ code. For more read http://eprints.maths.manchester.ac.uk/2450/1/catalog.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your the suggestion with the C++ Eigen library. I will give it a try and see if I am able to call the function from my Fortran code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to compute the logarithm of a matrix, you need to compute the eigenvalues *λ<sub>{1,2,3}</sub>* of your original matrix. If all your eigenvalues are bigger then `ZERO`, then you can compute the logarithm.

So the steps I would take are :

1. Compute the eigenvalues *λ<sub>{1,2,3}</sub>* and its corresponding eigenvectors ***v**<sub>{1,2,3}</sub>*.
2. Check if all eigenvalues are bigger then `ZERO`.
3. If condition (2) is satisfied, compute the `Log` of the eigenvalues.
4. Using the logarithmic values, reconstruct the matrix with the eigenvectors.

Simple methods to compute the eigenvector and eigenvalues of a matrix can be found in [numerical recipes](http://numerical.recipes/) (check the old book section). More advanced methods can be based on [blas and lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) - you are interested in the routine [dgeev](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgeev.f).

The best way would be to attempt to implement the eigendecomposition yourself as it is just a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: Eigenvalues of a 3x3 matrix can be computed directly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#3%C3%973_matrices

Comment: I have implemented a subroutine for the matrix logarithm according to the way proposed by @kvantour and it worked out fine. Is it helpful to post my code here for others?

Comment: @MechanicalOlli There is no harm in doing so. I would place it in the original question (by edit). It is for sure true that other people might benefit from it.